# Как настроить порядок выгрузки картинок из 1С в CommerceML?

Tags: 1с

Настраиваю выгрузку из 1С на сайт через стандартный CommerceML протокол. Сайт не на Битриксе, 1С 8.3 + Управление небольшой фирмой.

У большинства товаров есть несколько картинок, часть с описанием. В 1Ске они выстраиваются по алфавиту (название файла картинки + описание (если задано)). Но при выгрузке они идут в каком-то непонятном порядке.

Думал со стороны сайта массив фотографий сортировать по алфавиту - но не выйдет, потому что если у фотки нет описания - вместо него 1Ска выставляет название файла. Т.е. некоторые будут "описание", а некоторые "название файла".

Собственно, вопросы:

1. Как можно настроить порядок выгрузки фотографий в 1С?
2. Можно ли в 1С выключить вывод описания фотографии, если не задано описание напрямую?